# Complete Eejit's Guide to BGE -- recommendations?

Tags: game-engine

*In light of downvotes and comments it seems like I should delete this question, in hindsight it is obviously too vague.  But when I tried to delete it, I was presented with a dire warning about deleting any question with an answer -- this might result in being banned from asking questions!  If any moderator wishes to delete this question, go right ahead -- I regret having asked it.*

I would like to venture into BGE, but given my complete ignorance of game design software I think I'll need some tutorials, examples, etc.  Can anyone recommend their favourite Absolute Beginner's Guide to BGE, preferably video format?  I have a CGcookie membership so can access their stuff, but have not been able to find anything there that fits the bill :-(  I'm also aware of the excellent ebook N00b to Pro, which has been very helpful to me in the past, but I thought a video overview might get me started faster, and a couple of recommends for really good ones would be even better.

Comment: If you are gonna be learning about game creation you are probably better off investing in something more future proof with a wider applicability like Unity or Unreal engine. BGE is not really a flexible gaming solution for now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Step 1: Open Blender

Step 2: Switch the top to Blender Game

Step 3: Switch the bottom to Logic Bricks

Step 4: Muck around for about 6 months making little random push-the-cube-off-the-shelf games.

Step 5: Learn Python

---

There is very little you can do to speed the learning process. If this is your first game engine, it will take you six months to learn, regardless of engine, programming languages, modeling pipelines etc. It just takes time.

Comment: I completely disagree. you do not need 6 months. You  can make your first game much sooner then that, granted you will not know everything, but 6 months is absurd. On the other hand, if all you do is "mess around" and not learn anything then it will take you much longer then 6 months.

Comment: Or it might take more than 6 months... Clicking and pushing randomly will only get you so far. You will for sure advance faster and prevent frustration  if you take the time to educate yourself and get to know the tools, use them for what they are designed for and having control over them (as opposed of the tools controling you)...

Comment: You can follow tutorials and guides and feel like you have made a game you will not have made your own. In the world of baking, all who follow a recipe end up with a cake. In the digital world, those who follow tutorials end up with the tutorial-creators art/game.

Comment: In six months of 'mucking around' you will do all of the false-starts and learn how not to do things in the way that following tutorials will never teach you. Knowing best practice because someone told you is quite different to knowing best practice because you've 'been there done that.'

Comment: And perhaps my 'mucking about' is slightly deceptive. When I 'muck about' with a program, I am simultaneously researching how to do specific things. So I'm not following a tutorial, but if I want to know if there's a good way to flatten a face, I'll google it.

Comment: There are a huge number of people who can only follow and combine tutorials, and I want to stop that happening.

Comment: @sdfgeoff This actually described my first experiences with the BGE exactly! (and I'm still gradually getting through step 5)

Comment: @David I can count the number of BGE tutorials that I followed on one hand. (almost) everything I know in the BGE came from "messing around."

Comment: Ouch, first time I've been downvoted.  I did do some research, honest -- I just didn't find anything that looked useful.  Am working on my Python skills actively.  Maybe I should go on with Blender Python scripting for a while yet before trying to understand any game engine.  Apologies to those who found this a useless or low-quality question.

Comment: @sdfgeoff and come to think of it, it was more like - OH COOL! Rigid Body Physics! *knock the cubes down game* OH COOL! Edit Object - Add Object!! *Shot the cubes over game* OH COOL! Integer Properties!! *Destroy cubes with health bars and limited ammo game*